# Create JAR for project or project-build

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jar

I have a Scala/Java project called `mstm` in Intellij. I want to extract a JAR file from it.

I can see that I have two options: `mstm` and `mstm-build`.

What is the difference between the two?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but you may want to use sbt (http://www.scala-sbt.org) to bundle your project. It works with Scala and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mstm-build is equivalent to opening up the console/terminal in IntelliJ and typing in...

```
> sbt package
```

The reasoning behind this is that the symbol with the blue waves next to `mstm-build` means "sbt task" in the `Run > Edit Configuration > New SBT Task`  menu and sbt tasks typically correspond to sbt terminal commands. For more on sbt, read

http://alvinalexander.com/downloads/scala/Scala-SBT-Documentation.pdf